# anonymous excel rest api to publicly shared files

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I am able to successfully authenticate and read/write to an excel file using the rest APIs. However, I have a file that is publicly shared (no login is required) and I can embed this file on a public website. What I'm wondering is if I can access / read the file with the rest API without getting an accesstoken? I'd rather not have to impersonate a real user .

Thanks

Barry

Answer (score 1):

The cloud service that executes Excel operations (WAC) is stateless. It uses the MS-WOPI protocol (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh622722(v=office.12).aspx) to fetch the content from a storage service and to put it back in.

According to this section (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh622899(v=office.12).aspx), the Authorization header is a MUST on all requests.

However, since you can share Excel workbooks with "anybody with a link", there must be a way for WAC to fetch .xlsx files for anonymous users. Though I don't know how. I found this reference site that may give you the information you need - http://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Anyway, you may be better off designating an account for such "implicit" actions.

Zlatko